# javascript error return select html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, select

If I select the cinema from the select menu it doesn't return the title of the film present in the array programmazione.

```js
var programmazione = [{
    titolo: 'matrix',
    cinema: ['garibaldi', 'politeama']
  },
  {
    titolo: 'limitless',
    cinema: ['politeama', 'italia']
  },
  {
    titolo: 'forrest gump',
    cinema: ['italia', 'popoazzurra']
  }
];

var nodoSelectCinema;
var nodoMostraFilm;
var nodoListaFilm;

function calcolaListaFilm(cinema) {
  try {
    var listaFilm = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < programmazione.length; i++) {
      var film = programmazione[i];
      var j = 0;
      while ((j < film.cinema.length) && film.cinema[i] != cinema) {
        j++;
      }
      if (j < film.cinema.length) {
        listaFilm.push(film.titolo);
      }
    }
    console.log(listaFilm);
    return listaFilm;
  } catch (e) {
    alert("calcolaListaFilm" + e);
  }
}

function calcolaListaCinema() {
  try {
    var listaCinema = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < programmazione.length; i++) {
      var film = programmazione[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < film.cinema.length; j++) {
        var cinema = film.cinema[j];
        listaCinema[cinema] = true;
      }
    }
    return listaCinema;
  } catch (e) {
    alert("calcolaListaCinema" + e);
  }
}


function visualizzaListaFilm(listaFilm) {
  try {
    while (nodoListaFilm.childNodes.length > 0) {
      nodoListaFilm.removeChild(nodoListaFilm.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < listaFilm.length; i++) {
      var film = listaFilm[i];
      var nodoFilm = document.createElement("li");
      nodoListaFilm.appendChild(nodoFilm);
      var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(film);
      nodoFilm.appendChild(nodoTesto);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("visualizzaListaFilm" + e);
  }
}

function creaSelect(nodoSelect, opzioni) {
  try {
    for (var opzione in opzioni) {
      var nodoOpzione = document.createElement("option");
      nodoOpzione.value = opzione;
      var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(opzione);
      nodoOpzione.appendChild(nodoTesto);
      nodoSelect.appendChild(nodoOpzione);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("creaSelect" + e);
  }
}

function gestoreMostraFilm() {
  try {
    var cinema = nodoSelectCinema.value;
    var listaFilm = calcolaListaFilm(cinema);
    visualizzaListaFilm(listaFilm);
  } catch (e) {
    alert("gestoreMostraFilm" + e);
  }
}

function inzializza() {
  try {
    nodoSelectCinema = document.getElementById("selectCinema");
    nodoMostraFilm = document.getElementById("mostraFilm");
    nodoListaFilm = document.getElementById("listaFilm");
    var listaCinema = calcolaListaCinema();
    creaSelect(nodoSelectCinema, listaCinema);
    nodoListaFilm.onclick = gestoreMostraFilm();
  } catch (e) {
    alert("inizializza" + e);
  }
}

window.onload = inzializza;
```

```html
<select id="selectCinema"></select>
<input type="button" id="mostraFilm" value="Mostra Film">
<br>
<ol id="listaFilm"></ol>
```

Comment: i don't know which is the function that doesn't work, if i knew it, i didn't write :D the function that return the select option is creaSelect() and calcolaListaCinema()

Comment: The script works (if we ignore the fact that this line `nodoListaFilm.onclick = gestoreMostraFilm();` is probably wrong): https://jsfiddle.net/d5pgnkj6/; Is `inzializza()` executed?

Comment: the script works, it create the select option but if you change the option, the result doesn't change. inizializza is executed

Answer (score 2):

I found two places where you can make changes that should fix your code.

First, you are not assigning a click listener to your button.

```
nodoListaFilm.onclick = gestoreMostraFilm();
```

should be

```
nodoMostraFilm.addEventListener('click', gestoreMostraFilm);
```

Second, the while loop in your calcolaListaFilm function is pointing to i instead of j.

```
while ((j < film.cinema.length) && film.cinema[i] != cinema) {
```

should be

```
while ((j < film.cinema.length) && film.cinema[j] != cinema) {
```

```js
var programmazione = [{
    titolo: 'matrix',
    cinema: ['garibaldi', 'politeama']
  },
  {
    titolo: 'limitless',
    cinema: ['politeama', 'italia']
  },
  {
    titolo: 'forrest gump',
    cinema: ['italia', 'popoazzurra']
  }
];

var nodoSelectCinema;
var nodoMostraFilm;
var nodoListaFilm;

function calcolaListaFilm(cinema) {
  try {
    var listaFilm = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < programmazione.length; i++) {
      var film = programmazione[i];
      var j = 0;
      while ((j < film.cinema.length) && film.cinema[j] != cinema) {
        j++;
      }
      if (j < film.cinema.length) {
        listaFilm.push(film.titolo);
      }
    }
    console.log(listaFilm);
    return listaFilm;
  } catch (e) {
    alert("calcolaListaFilm" + e);
  }
}

function calcolaListaCinema() {
  try {
    var listaCinema = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < programmazione.length; i++) {
      var film = programmazione[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < film.cinema.length; j++) {
        var cinema = film.cinema[j];
        listaCinema[cinema] = true;
      }
    }
    return listaCinema;
  } catch (e) {
    alert("calcolaListaCinema" + e);
  }
}


function visualizzaListaFilm(listaFilm) {
  try {
    while (nodoListaFilm.childNodes.length > 0) {
      nodoListaFilm.removeChild(nodoListaFilm.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < listaFilm.length; i++) {
      var film = listaFilm[i];
      var nodoFilm = document.createElement("li");
      nodoListaFilm.appendChild(nodoFilm);
      var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(film);
      nodoFilm.appendChild(nodoTesto);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("visualizzaListaFilm" + e);
  }
}

function creaSelect(nodoSelect, opzioni) {
  try {
    for (var opzione in opzioni) {
      var nodoOpzione = document.createElement("option");
      nodoOpzione.value = opzione;
      var nodoTesto = document.createTextNode(opzione);
      nodoOpzione.appendChild(nodoTesto);
      nodoSelect.appendChild(nodoOpzione);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("creaSelect" + e);
  }
}

function gestoreMostraFilm() {
  try {
    var cinema = nodoSelectCinema.value;
    var listaFilm = calcolaListaFilm(cinema);
    visualizzaListaFilm(listaFilm);
  } catch (e) {
    alert("gestoreMostraFilm" + e);
  }
}

function inzializza() {
  try {
    nodoSelectCinema = document.getElementById("selectCinema");
    nodoMostraFilm = document.getElementById("mostraFilm");
    nodoListaFilm = document.getElementById("listaFilm");
    var listaCinema = calcolaListaCinema();
    creaSelect(nodoSelectCinema, listaCinema);
    nodoMostraFilm.addEventListener('click', gestoreMostraFilm);
  } catch (e) {
    alert("inizializza" + e);
  }
}

window.onload = inzializza;
```

```html
<select id="selectCinema"></select>
<input type="button" id="mostraFilm" value="Mostra Film">
<br>
<ol id="listaFilm"></ol>
```

Comment: it works, perfect! thank you! do you know why if i wrote nodoMostraFilm.onclick = gestoreMostraFilm(); doesn't works, but if wrote nodoMostraFilm.onclick = gestoreMostraFilm; it works. do you know why?

Comment: Adding the () executes the function. You want to assign the function to the click event, not execute it. It should only be executed when the click event takes place.

Comment: Right! Thank you again :)